# How to specify # of failed login attempts for account lock in MVC 4 w/ default simplemembership provider

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, simplemembership

How can you specify the # of failed logon attempts with the default simplemembership provider in ASP.NET MVC 4?  I see there is an unlock account method but I don't see anywhere you can specify the # of failed attempts that cause the account to lock.  If you were specifying it in MVC 3 you could specify maxInvalidPasswordAttempts in web.config under the provider.  However, with MVC4 simplemembership you don't set up the provider in web.config.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It turns out simplemembership provider tracks the failed logins but it is up to you to catch the failed login attempts on user login with something like...

```
if(WebSecurity.IsAccountLockedOut(model.UserName,4,10000)){
                    return RedirectToAction("LockedAccount");
                }
```

Which of course leads to how to log them in once they reset their password.  I chose to log them in directly in the password reset action.  I could have put another field in the userprofile to track password being reset and bypass the check but figured it was not worth it.